# How do I redirect an Error 403 to root in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am not very firm in Apache, so please excuse if the question might seem a bit obvious.
I would like to redirect requests that would result in an Error 403 in specific directories to my webservers root by means of a .htaccess file.
so https://thedomain.com/secretlair/ -> https://thedomain.com

so far i used:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) https://thedomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

which works but creates the problem of also redirecting
https://thedomain.com/secretlair/thefile.txt to https://thedomain.com/thefile.txt

what do I need to change to make this work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a `ErrorDocument` handler for `403` error instead of a rewrite rule like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 https://thedomain.com/
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thanks so much. That works fine.
However, when i also have a subdomain ( sub.thedomain.com ), which at the moment resolves to an empty directory (thedomain.com/sub).
There it does not work but I guess this must have to do with my providers settings...

Comment: Inside `/sub/.htaccess` you may try: `ErrorDocument 403 https://sub.thedomain.com/`

Comment: Thanks. but that did not do the trick. It seems that the provider cooks his own soup here...