# From where this link is generating ? i want to redirect this link to blog home page

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

https://www.duplichecker.com/blog/.php
i did google try to apply redirect in .htacess but can't also i try to apply redirect in header.php file but it not detect my solution and show

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /blog/.php on this
>   server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47074147/4934937)):

```
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
```

into your .htaccess file. This will rediect all 403 (forbidden) requests to your index.php instead of displaying the error message page.